# Float For CPT Archive Grid Layout

Tags: css-float

```
.wpsites-portfolio .portfolio {
float: left;
clear: none;
padding: 0 15px 15px;
padding: 0 1.5rem 1.5rem;
width: 33.33333333%;
}

.wpsites-portfolio .portfolio:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
clear: left;
}
```

Can't get this code to work. It only displays the first 2 featured images on the CPT portfolio archive page rather than 3. It then displays one after another.

wpsites-portfolio is a custom body class i added for the CPT archive file in the Twenty Twelve theme

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove padding and then check...

Comment: hahaha. As simple as that. Thanks. Not sure why i needed it in this first place.